# How to download excel file with styles on it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

I'm trying to add styles to an excel file and then downloading it, the file is downloaded with the data but the styles are not there. Can someone help me with anything with I'm missing?

```
            IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;
            application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2016;
            IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Create(1);
            IWorksheet namedSheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
            namedSheet.Range["A1"].Text = "CustomerID";       
            namedSheet.Range["B1"].Text = "CompanyName";
            IStyle bodyStyle = workbook.Styles.Add("BodyStyle");
            bodyStyle.BeginUpdate();
            bodyStyle.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(15, 19, 22);
            bodyStyle.EndUpdate();
            IStyle headerStyle = workbook.Styles.Add("HeaderStyle");
            headerStyle.BeginUpdate();
            headerStyle.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 174, 33);
            headerStyle.EndUpdate();
            namedSheet.Range["A10"].CellStyleName = "BodyStyle";
            namedSheet.Range["A1"].CellStyleName = "HeaderStyle";
            HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            string separator = ",";                      //delimeter
            workbook.SaveAs(ms, separator);
            ms.Flush();
            byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Close();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.xls");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Write(Response.Output);
        }
```

Only excel data is displayed in the downloaded file, not the styles.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the styles are not persisted in the file is because you are not using the correct SyncFusion API.
You need to use the `style.BeginUpdate()` and `style.EndUpdate()` methods for styles to persist!

For example:

```
    IStyle style = workbook.Styles.Add("style1");
    style.BeginUpdate();
    style.FillPattern = ExcelPattern.Gradient;
    style.Interior.Gradient.GradientStyle = ExcelGradientStyle.Vertical;
    style.Interior.Gradient.BackColor = Color.Black;
    style.Interior.Gradient.ForeColor = Color.Beige;
    //Apply style to range of cells
    namedSheet.Range["A10"].CellStyleName = "style1";
    style.EndUpdate();
    workbook.SaveAs(@"c:\temp\test.xlsx");

    workbook.Close();
    excelEngine.Dispose();
```

Comment: I've used this format, it was just too lengthy so I couldn't post all code, when I save the file using workbook.Saveas(@"c:\temp\test.xlsx");  the styles are ther in the file whch is saved to my comupter. But on the downloaded file, it's only data. I think there is error only in the way I am writing the code to download the file

Comment: Please look at my code snippet, you should put the folowing 2 lines inside their respective BeginUpdate & EndUpdate blocks.
`namedSheet.Range["A10"].CellStyleName = "BodyStyle";
 namedSheet.Range["A1"].CellStyleName = "HeaderStyle";`

Comment: Tried this, but still no style.

Answer (score 0):

```
using GemBox.Spreadsheet;

.....

 worksheet.Cells[row += x, y].Value = ".Style.Font.Color =";
 worksheet.Cells[row, x].Value = "Color.Blue";
 worksheet.Cells[row, x].Style.Font.Color = SpreadsheetColor.FromName(ColorName.Blue);

 worksheet.Cells[row += x, y].Value = ".Style.Font.Italic =";
 worksheet.Cells[row, x].Value = "true";
 worksheet.Cells[row, x].Style.Font.Italic = true;

 worksheet.Cells[row += x, y].Value = ".Style.Font.Name =";
 worksheet.Cells[row, x].Value = "Comic Sans MS";
 worksheet.Cells[row, x].Style.Font.Name = "Comic Sans MS";

 worksheet.Cells[row += x, y].Value = ".Style.Font.Size =";
 worksheet.Cells[row, x].Value = "18 * 20";
 worksheet.Cells[row, x].Style.Font.Size = 18 * 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a plain text separated by comma (,) and there is no styling attached to it. When you apply any styles to cells and save the file as CSV then the styles are not preserved. This is the behaviour of Microsoft Excel. We have modified your code to generate xlsx file where the applied styles are preserved. Please find the updated code below.

```
using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
            {
                IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;
                application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2016;
                IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Create(1);
                IWorksheet namedSheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
                namedSheet.Range["A1"].Text = "CustomerID";
                namedSheet.Range["B1"].Text = "CompanyName";
                IStyle bodyStyle = workbook.Styles.Add("BodyStyle");
                bodyStyle.BeginUpdate();
                bodyStyle.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(15, 19, 22);
                bodyStyle.EndUpdate();
                IStyle headerStyle = workbook.Styles.Add("HeaderStyle");
                headerStyle.BeginUpdate();
                headerStyle.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 174, 33);
                headerStyle.EndUpdate();
                namedSheet.Range["A10"].CellStyleName = "BodyStyle";
                namedSheet.Range["A1"].CellStyleName = "HeaderStyle";

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                workbook.SaveAs(ms);
                ms.Flush();
                byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
                ms.Close();
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.xlsx");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            }
```

We are also sharing the sample for your reference which can be downloaded from following link.

Sample Link: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Sample-1943806173.zip

Please refer to below documentation to know more on Excel file creation in MVC platform.

Documentation Link: https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/xlsio/create-read-edit-excel-files-in-asp-net-mvc-c-sharp#create-a-simple-excel-report

Regards,

Abirami